# stream has already been operated upon or closed, gained exception when trying to create Racers

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following class :

```
public List<Racer> createListOfRacers() throws IOException {
    Stream<String> abbreviationsOfRacers = fileLoader.createStreamFromFile("src/main/resources/abbreviations.txt");

    Stream<Racer> racerList = abbreviationsOfRacers
            .map(this::createRacer);

    return racerList.collect(toList());
}
```

which throws exception in this line :

```
.map(this::createRacer);
```

Methods to create racer that consists in the same class :

```
private Racer createRacer(String line) {
    return new Racer(extractAbbreviationOfTheRacer(line), extractNameOfTheRacer(line), extractTeamOfTheRacer(line));
}

private String extractNameOfTheRacer(String line) {
    return line.substring(line.indexOf('_') + 1, line.lastIndexOf('_'));
}

private String extractTeamOfTheRacer(String line) {
    return line.substring(line.lastIndexOf('_') + 1);
}

private String extractAbbreviationOfTheRacer(String line) {
    return line.substring(0, line.indexOf('_'));
}
```

The Racer Class :

```
public class Racer {

    private String abbrevition;
    private String name;
    private String team;
    private String result;


    public Racer(String abbrevition, String name, String team) {
        this.abbrevition = abbrevition;
        this.name = name;
        this.team = team;
    }

    public Racer() {
    }
```

Abbreviations.txt file :

```
DRR_Daniel Ricciardo_RED BULL RACING TAG HEUER
SVF_Sebastian Vettel_FERRARI
LHM_Lewis Hamilton_MERCEDES
KRF_Kimi Raikkonen_FERRARI ...
```

FileLoader class :

```
public Stream<String> createStreamFromFile(String file) throws IOException {

    try (Stream<String> streamFromFile = Files.lines(Paths.get(file))) {

        return streamFromFile;
    }

}
```

I read about Stream Supplier but I can't figured It out so I will be grateful for any help how to fix my program.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement to create a stream. Thus, the stream will be closed when the method returns which defeats your purpose.

From the above resource (**emphasis mine**)

> The try-with-resources statement is a try statement that declares one or more resources. A resource is an object that must be closed after the program is finished with it. **The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement**. Any object that implements java.lang.AutoCloseable, which includes all objects which implement java.io.Closeable, can be used as a resource.

A `Stream` extends `BaseStream` which extends `AutoCloseable`

---

Change your code to return the stream like

```
public Stream<String> createStreamFromFile(String file) throws IOException {
    return Files.lines(Paths.get(file));
}
```

Comment: @HadiJ No, it cannot. Can you be more specific? It can still throw an `IOException` if the file is not found